# Bamboo - SonarQube multimodule maven project skip the child module

Tags: maven, sonarqube, bamboo

I have created SonarQube task in Bamboo. I have one parent pom which contains 4 modules. While running the task it skips the child tasks.I am not getting the root cause???

Parent POM.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mastercard.mpts.emailsms</groupId>
    <artifactId>emailsms-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>EmailSMS Application</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>ESBMsgProcessor</module>
        <module>EmailSMSService</module>
        <module>SMTPMsgProcessor</module>
        <module>ESBSMSService</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Following is child for SMTPMsgProcessor

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mastercard.mpts.emailsms</groupId>
    <artifactId>emailsms-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mastercard.mpts.emailsms</groupId>
  <artifactId>smtpmsgprocessor</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SMTPMsgProcessor</name>
  <description>Handle Email for SMTP</description>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
```

Result of SonarQube plan is :

```
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] 
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] emailsms-parent .................................... SUCCESS [ 33.879 s]
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] ESBMsgProcessor .................................... SKIPPED
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] EmailSMSService .................................... SKIPPED
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] SMTPMsgProcessor ................................... SKIPPED
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] ESBSMSService ...................................... SKIPPED
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] Total time: 34.260 s
30-Mar-2017 08:33:10    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-30T08:33:10-05:00
30-Mar-2017 08:33:11    [INFO] Final Memory: 48M/3050M
```

I have not added anything to get skipped.Also I am not able to see soanr analysis for the same as modules are getting skipped.

Answer (score 5):

The `sonar:sonar` Maven goal is an aggregator one: this means that it is triggered only once on the root module. It's then up to the SonarQube Scanner for Maven to analyse the modules on its own.

So from a Maven point of view, it looks like the modules are skipped, but actually they are analyzed by SonarQube correctly. Go to your SonarQube web interface, and you will find the modules inside your project.